# Controlling a Spinner inside a ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have created a ListView with a custom adapter. Now I have 5 rows inside the ListView and each row has a Spinner. But how can I set a ItemClickEvent on each spinner and know which one has changed?

```
SortedSettingList = settingsList.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

if (SettingListAdapter == null)
{
    //Fill the DataSource of the ListView with the Array of Names
    SettingListAdapter = new SettingListAdapter(Context, SortedSettingList);
    ListViewSettings.Adapter = SettingListAdapter;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please, share your adapter ´getView´ method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At start you should handle the click event inside the adapter you've created.
Inside the adapter, you should have a code which looks like that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  SpinnerView spinnerView = (SpinnerView) convertView; //cast the convertView to be an instance of your spinner view
        spinnerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //handle item click
            }
        });
        return spinnerView;
    }
```

It depends which adapter type you are using.
But the idea is the same. when you are setting the item you will set his delegations.

Comment: the Q is for Xamarin (C#)